# How to remove leading indentation from algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I am typing an algorithm using the following preamble

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand{\LeftComment}[1]{\(\triangleright\) #1}%
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicindent{0.6em}%
```

The whole algorithm has a indentation to the left as shown in the image below. 
How can I remove this indent?

[image]

This is the algorithm code

```
{\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \floatname{algorithm}{Alg.}
  \caption{Projected SGD for Model A, Batch Size=1}\label{alg:tellmain}
  \begin{algorithmic}%[1]
    \State Given: $\cF, \cFc$. Hyperparameters: $\alpha, \eta, \rS$.
    \For{each fact $f' \in \cF$}
    \State Mark $f'$ as seen.
    \For{$\rS$ steps}
    \State Sample $\fc = (\bar{t}, \bar{r})$ from $\cFc$.
    \State Set $f = f'$ with $p=0.5$,
    \State $\qquad$or sample $f$ from seen facts.
    \State Let $\vvv = \sigma(\ip{\rc}{\tc} - \ip{\r}{\t})$.
    \State \LeftComment{Fix $\e$ and optimize ${J}$}.
    \State {\small $\grad{\r}{\Jr} = {-\t}\vvv, \ \grad{\rc}{\Jr} = {\tc}\vvv$}
  \State {\small$ (\r; \rc) = \proj((\r; \rc) - \eta ((\grad{\r}{\Jr}; \grad{\rc}{\Jr}) + 2\alpha (\r; \rc)))$}
    \State \LeftComment{Fix $\r$ and optimize ${J}$}
    \State {\small$\grad{\t}{\Je} = {-\r}\vvv, \ \grad{\tc}{\Je} = {\rc_1}\vvv$}
    \State {\small $(\t; \tc) = \proj((\t; \tc) - \eta ((\grad{\t}{\Jr}; \grad{\tc}{\Jr}) + 2\alpha (\t; \tc)))$}
    \EndFor
    \EndFor
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure there is an easy way.  Here is a hack:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\algorithmic}
  {\ALG@tlm\z@}{\leftmargin\z@\ALG@tlm\z@}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```